# Maven Rest APIs

Tags: java, maven, maven-repository

Can someone help me out in finding the Maven Rest APIs?

Maven Rest API to get the Vulnerability details based on the groupId and artifactId and Version.

Maven Rest API to get the Latest stable version that is present in the Maven web repository.

I have tried using the https://ossindex.sonatype.org/doc/rest APIs to get the vulnerability details.
But this API has some Rate Limiting. Due to this, we cannot get more than 128 records in a single run of the application.

For Maven Latest version I have used https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=a:guice&rows=20&wt=json
to get the latest versions for an artifactId and gooupId. But we have Alpha beta versions as well in this API. I want to get only the stable versions.

Answer (score 1):

To get the vulnerabilities, you can add the [`Snyk Maven Plugin`](https://github.com/snyk/snyk-maven-plugin) to your `pom.xml`.

To make get the latest stable version for a specific Maven package, you can use the `solrsearch` endpoint, documented on the [Maven Central API Rest API Guide](https://central.sonatype.org/search/rest-api-guide/).

Comment: I want a Rest API through which I would like to fetch the vulnerabilities by passing artifactid, groupid and version. So, basically I want to check vulnerabilities for some versions that I have using this API.